# Angular 8 (ECONNRESET) Proxy Error from port 4200 to any port Api Net Core 2.1 backend uses

Tags: angular, proxy, vpn, ntlm, econnreset

Ihave seen this question asked but in my case, i have tried i think all answers with no success. I have to authenticate with Windows credentials though VPN in the app the team is developing, then when we want to test changes we do **ng serve --port 4200 --proxy-config proxy.config.js** we all get this..

**[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request http://localhost:4200/api/users/currentuser from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:4200 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)**

We work this around by deploying to Backend NET Core Web project wwwroot folder, but we lose the debugging capabilities of ng serve and Angular Development Live Server. It's time consuming build and copy each time to visualize any big or small change in front-end. It is interesting there is one guy in the team that can serve the full Angular app from http://localhost:4200

We are working thoguh VPN all the time so not sure how this might behave directly connected to corporate network.

I only use api and graphql contexts, Here is my Proxy file.

```
const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');
// I tried also with NTLM version with same issue result
// const Agent = require('agentkeepalive-ntlm');

module.exports = {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:53904',
            secure: false,
            pathRewrite : {"^/api" : "http://localhost:53904/api"},
            agent: new Agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000
            }),
            onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                let key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
                    proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            }
        },
      '/graphql': {
        target: 'http://localhost:53904',
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite : {"^/graphql" : "http://localhost:53904/graphql"},
        agent: new Agent({
            maxSockets: 100,
            keepAlive: true,
            maxFreeSockets: 10,
            keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
            timeout: 6000000,
            keepAliveTimeout: 90000
        }),
        onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
            let key = 'www-authenticate';
            proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
                proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
        }
    }
};
```